# Airflow PigOperator throws "No such file or directory" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

Am unable to find out the issue that i have made, logs are shown below.
The DAG, connection, pig script that i have created are also shown below.

DAG:

```
from airflow.operators import BashOperator, PigOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'hadoop',
    'start_date': datetime.now()
    }
dag = DAG(dag_id='ETL-DEMO',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval='@hourly')

fly_task_1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='fly_task_1',
            bash_command='sleep 10 ; echo "fly_task_2"',
            dag=dag)
fly_task_2 = PigOperator(
            task_id='fly_task_2',
            pig='/pig/sample.pig',
            pig_cli_conn_id='pig_cli',
            dag=dag)

fly_task_2.set_upstream(fly_task_1)
```

PIG SCRIPT:

```
rmf /onlyvinish/sample_out;
a_load = load '/onlyvinish/sample.txt' using PigStorage(',');
a_gen = foreach a_load generate (int)$0 as a;
b_gen = foreach a_gen generate a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5;
store b_gen into '/onlyvinish/sample_out' using PigStorage(',');
```

Connections:
 [image]

Log for the failed task:

```
[2017-01-24 00:03:27,199] {models.py:168} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/hadoop/airflow/dags/ETL.py
[2017-01-24 00:03:27,276] {jobs.py:2042} INFO - Subprocess PID is 8532
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,410] {models.py:168} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/hadoop/airflow/dags/ETL.py
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,487] {models.py:1078} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: ETL-DEMO.fly_task_2 2017-01-24 00:03:07.199790 [queued]>
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,496] {models.py:1078} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: ETL-DEMO.fly_task_2 2017-01-24 00:03:07.199790 [queued]>
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,496] {models.py:1266} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2017-01-24 00:03:29,533] {models.py:1289} INFO - Executing <Task(PigOperator): fly_task_2> on 2017-01-24 00:03:07.199790
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,550] {pig_operator.py:64} INFO - Executing: rmf /onlyvinish/sample_out;

a_load = load '/onlyvinish/sample.txt' using PigStorage(',');

a_gen = foreach a_load generate (int)$0 as a;
b_gen = foreach a_gen generate a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5;

store b_gen into '/onlyvinish/sample_out' using PigStorage(',');
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,612] {pig_hook.py:67} INFO - pig -f /tmp/airflow_pigop_sm5bjE/tmpNP0ZXM
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,620] {models.py:1364} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow-1.7.2.dev0-py2.7.egg/airflow/models.py", line 1321, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow-1.7.2.dev0-py2.7.egg/airflow/operators/pig_operator.py", line 66, in execute
    self.hook.run_cli(pig=self.pig)
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow-1.7.2.dev0-py2.7.egg/airflow/hooks/pig_hook.py", line 72, in run_cli
    cwd=tmp_dir)
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,623] {models.py:1388} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2017-01-24 00:03:29,636] {models.py:1409} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

- Airflow: 1.7.2
- Python: 2.7
- Rhel:6.7

Please let me know what am doing wrong.?

Comment: I'd say that `pig` is not in your PATH.

Comment: If thats the case how  the PIG content is shown in logs.? @Jean-FrançoisFabre